# tika-server v1.5 only accepts connections from localhost

Tags: localhost, apache-tika

All, I've downloaded tika-server v1.5 hoping to access the server from our network other than "localhost".  There was an issue addressed in TIKA-1196 (link below).  Am I missing something by assuming that by downloading tika-server.jar (v1.5) I would pick up the fix for this?

https://issues.apache.org/jira/i#browse/TIKA-1196?jql=project%20%3D%20TIKA%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%201.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this comment on the bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-1196?focusedCommentId=13840066&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-13840066):

> for now I've introduced a 'host' property defaulted to 'localhost'

So, when you start the server up, it defaults to localhost (as before), but you can optionally tell it to listen on all addresses if you want:

```
$ java -jar tika-server-1.5.jar -host 0.0.0.0
INFO: Starting Tikaserver 1.5
INFO: Starting Tika Server Apache Tika 1.5
INFO: Setting the server's publish address to be http://0.0.0.0:9998/
```

And with netstat you can then see that it's running on 0.0.0.0:

```
$ netstat -nl | grep 99
tcp6       0      0 :::9998                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: This works perfectly - I made the mistake of looking at the patch file for the commandline option, and missed your note in the comments section.